# TUI (text user interface) for D?

Tags: d, tui

I would like to write a console app with text UI in D. I looked at curses, but it seems that it works only on unix. Are there any cross-patform alternatives?

Comment: There are curses ports for windows. There is nothing that will work absolutely everywhere, but curses is not a bad choice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My terminal.d could be used as a foundation for a TUI library.

https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/terminal.d

It has no required dependencies, so you can simply download that one file and start building with `dmd yourfile.d terminal.d`. Here's an example program getting input: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/book/chapter_12/07/input.d

You can also use `terminal.moveTo(x, y); terminal.color(Color.green, Color.black); terminal.writef("something"); terminal.flush();` and such to move and draw.

Look for `version(Demo)` in terminal.d itself for a `main` which handles all kinds of input events, including mouse events.

While terminal.d mostly offers lower-level functions (its main high level function is `terminal.getline`, great for line based apps but not TUIs), it should give all the foundation needed to write a little text widget library.

and I think someone might have done that once but I don't recall where.

terminal.d works on Windows and Posix systems, for the most common terminals like xterm. ncurses is more comprehensive and probably has fewer bugs on more obscure targets but terminal.d, being a single file, is easier to build.

Answer (score 2):

That was true long ago. However, `ncurses` is known to work nicely on Windows as well. The easiest way to build it on Windows is inside the [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io) shell. There is really no other cross-platform alternative to Curses (find out why they named the project "curses" and you will find why there is no good alternative).